# Subquery in hibernate not working

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

Here is my query in HQL which I want to execute.But it is not supported in hibernate as subqueries will work only in where and select clauses.But I need to perform an inner join to get the result for the convenience.How can I make it work in Hibernate?

```
select 
    format.formatName,final.filecount 
    from FORMATS format 
    inner join ( select count(file.fileId) as filecount,file.objFormat.formatId as consFormatId from FILES file where file.objProject.projectId=:proId group by file.objFormat.formatId) 
    as final 
    on format.formatId=final.consFormatId
```